# Passing a (simple) UDT To a TVP using IEnumerator <SqlDataRecord>

Tags: c#, table-valued-parameters

I have a User Defined Table Type that I am using as a TVP. All the members of the User Defined Table Type are primitive SQL data types. However, one column is a User Defined Type, say,

```
CREATE TYPE [udtCustom] FROM [nvarchar](7) NULL
```

(it's just a simple abstraction for consistence and easy of refactoring when declaring different columns and parameters etc.)

Here's my type:

```
CREATE TYPE myCustomType AS TABLE(
-- other columns here 
[ColumnName] [udtCustom] NULL,
-- other columns here
);
```

In C#, what should be the data type passed to SqlMetaData method when creating a 
`SqlDataRecord` object (to pass an `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` to `SqlDbType.Structured`)?

Should I use this constructor

```
SqlMetaData Constructor (String, SqlDbType)
```

and pass a primitive type

```
new SqlMetaData ("ColumnName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 7)
```

or, should I use this constructor

```
SqlMetaData Constructor (String, SqlDbType, Type, String)?
```

If so, what should be the type of the third parameter, Type

```
new SqlMetaData ("ColumnName", SqlDbType.Udt, [what goes here?], "udtCustom")?
```

Thanks in advance!